# Merging / joining data from neo4j and hbase

Tags: hadoop, neo4j, hbase

I have some data stored in neo4j and some data in hbase. Many times, for doing certain analysis and querying, I need to combine data from these two different sources into one and do some join . I can definitely write java code utilizing java apis for both hbase and neo4j. However I want to know if there is any readymade / existing framework / api which caters to this need in some way. For example accepting some minimal information to query both neo4j and hbase and some configuration information about how to map the data fetched from the two sources. I know this might be very rare requirement, but just want to know if there is anything like this exist which I never come across.

(Any other suggestion which will help me implement above is welcome.)

Comment: I dont know if there a Neo4j's procedure for habse, but it can be a good idea to look at

Comment: I didnt get what do you mean by "neo4j's procedure for hbase". Do you mean something like [these](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/)? I have never come across any procedure operating with some other data source than neo4j. Ohh...there might be some procedures that deal with CSV. But I guess thats mostly for import and its limited in scope. Or do I miss something and there are such set of neo4j procedures which deal with other datasources?

Comment: Yes this kind of procedure. 
In APOC (https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) there is already some procedures for dealing with  couchbase, mongo, elastic, cassandra, jdbc ...

Comment: HBase can be reached via JDBC, APOC has a apoc.load.jdbc procedure. So you can integrate a HBase-query into a Neo4j Cypher query ...

Comment: You could also migrate to JanusGraph backed by Hbase... All data could be in one location

Comment: @logisima I have huge timeseries data stored in hbase. If I have query: get rowkey corresponding to top ten timeseries values and then find nodes corresponding to those rowkeys. So I feel I will require to sort non-rowkey column in hbase and then get rowkeys corresponding to top 10 column values and get nodes corresponding to those rowkeys. Is this possible by any means with good performance? it seems that sorting on non rowkey column is main bottleneck.

Comment: So your performance problem seems to come from the hbase query right ?

Comment: Can say. Scanning whole hbase table to find rowkeys corresponding to top 10 values in column is slower. But I got to have a look at apoc procedures stated. It will be of great use.